# Type error 'int' is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

im facing problem in the following code resulting to TYPE ERROR:'int' is not callable

```
    import math 
itr = int(raw_input())
arr = []
for i in xrange(0,itr):
    inp = raw_input()
    a , b , c , d = [int(s) for s in inp.split()]
    if b==1:
        e = c
    else:
        g = d+1
        h = b-1
        e = c(math.pow(g , h))
    if e>=a:
        f = "ALIVE AND KICKING"
    else:
        f = "DEAD AND ROTTING"
    arr.append(f)
for i in xrange(0 ,itr):
    print arr[i]
```

please help ..... me with the problem

Comment: `c` is an integer. Why are you trying to call it with `math.pow(g,h)` as an argument? What do you expect the result of that line to be?

Comment: please see http://www.codechef.com/problems/PLZLYKME this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the method:

```
e = c * (g**h)
```

Instead of the pow function. ** is a built in operator in Python. So

```
print 2**8
```

would yield `256`. You can read about the ** operator and all other basic operators [on this website!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to multiply `c` by `math.pow(g, h)`, use [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
e = c * math.pow(g , h)
```